# How can I output HTML in this example?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, date, typescript

This is my function:

```
public static monthDay(month: number): string {
     let day = new Date().getDay();
     let year = new Date().getFullYear();
     return day + ", " + year;
}
```

I want to wrap `day` in `<span></span>` tags but I get `<span></span>` tags outputted.

I've tried this:

```
return "<span>" + day + ", " + "<\/span>" + year;
```

but I get `<span></span>` tags outputted.

I'm trying to output this in Angular2.

```
this.day = monthDay(this.month);
```

I get the output like this in HTML:

```
<span>13, </span>2017
```

while I need it to be wrapped in span tags not to output the span tags...

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: how have you displayed your output??

Comment: Tryy to use "</span>" instead of "<\/span>"?

Comment: Same output Hristo..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `[innerHtml]` property tag in your template, so that Angular accepts the (sanitized) HTML content without escaping special characters.

```
<div [innerHtml]="day"></div>
```

Comment: How can I do it if it is saved in the this.day scope?

Comment: Editing the answer appropriately

Answer (score 1):

Call the function from the markup itself as below

```
<span>{{monthDay(2)}}</span>
```

**Note:** 
I see that

```
public static monthDay(month: number): string {}
```

you are having input parameter but you are not passing while calling `this.day = monthDay();`

You can save it using

```
monthDay(){
    let day = new Date().getDay();
     let year = new Date().getFullYear();
     this.myDate = day + ", " + year;
     return this.myDate;
}
```

Declare myDate as string below class declaration

Comment: Calling a function directly in html template is not recommended at all...